# CSS3: Will mobile devices load background images when inside media queries?

Tags: css, mobile, loading, media-queries

If I have the following:

```
div {background: #000}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
     div {background: url(myimage.jpg)}
}
```

Will a 320px wide smartphone, for example, still download that background image?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried it ? Should be able to test by resizing your browser window. Instinctively, I would say it won't and would only appear if screen is over 1000px wide...

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the device. Generally, the idea is that only devices with a viewport wider than 1000px will download the image in the above example, but it's not guaranteed. Here's an interesting study on the subject: http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think myimage.jpg will be downloaded by smartphones with 320px screens.

If you have `dispaly:none` in a media query then the image will be downloaded to smaller screens, although not actually displayed.